# Calculating count for a position inside two values in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Having a pd.DataFrame like this:

[image]

Would like to calculate group by count for the first position after Status=='Start'(like for the Rank between the status values). In this example it should be like:

```
Status Count_after_start
  X      2
  Y      0
```

Is there any pandas-oriented solution to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Please include your example as text. Also, `df.loc[df['Status'].shift().eq('Start'), 'Status'].value_counts()` should be close to what you want?

Comment: Are you looking for a panda solution, or a sql solution (you tagged both)?

Comment: Also interested in sql variant to compare time execution with. Thanks!